# How to change date format in snowflake without changing date type to varchar?

Tags: date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, custom-data-type

I need to change only format of date **without changing data type** in one of the tables in snowflake, so i can't change global date format of my system.
If i use this statement is showing the format by default to `YYYY-MM-DD.`

```
 to_date(allocation_date_utc) as time_employee_date,
```

If i use this, i change data type to varchar,so that's not what i want.

```
 to_varchar(allocation_date_utc, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Is there any way to change the format **without changing data type** to varchar or char?

Comment: I’m not aware of any way of getting Snowflake to automatically display a specific date column in a format that differs from the global display setting. What’s the issue with using to_char? If you want this column to always be displayed in this way then you could create a view that uses to_char

Comment: It's a basic request as expected of a database. I don't want to keep my date as yyyy-mm-dd, and i want to have it as another type of date format. i have to keep it as date datatype, otherwise all the other app that are readying from it, will fail.  from our requirement, we can't have another view over table just because , there is not a way to change date format.

Comment: If you want to change the display format globally (for all date columns) then just set the DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT parameter (at the account, user or session level). If you only want to change that one date column then you have the two options I listed previously - if neither of these suit you then unfortunately you’ll just have to live with it

Comment: This question does not make any sense. How the database stores "dates" is just that how it stores dates. If you want to leave data in a "date" then how you see if when you query it will be present how the client you use (which might be the Snowflake Web UI) decides to show "dates", the client has nothing todo with the server. So if you want it to show different (presentation) present it how you want it, or if you want it to be real date, leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter a setting named `DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT` to specify how you would like dates to be displayed:

```
-- Displays as 2023-08-27
select to_date('2023-08-27');

alter session set DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDD';

-- Now displays as 20230827
select to_date('2023-08-27');
```

You can set this parameter at the account, user, or session level. If you need to make the setting permanent, you can set it at the account or user level:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters

There is a corresponding DATE_IMPORT_FORMAT that specifies the standard input format for dates if you want to change that to YYYYMMDD without dashes.